# GCC is installed on mac but can't find it in command line

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

I'm using OS X with Yosemite 10.10.5 and I know I have XCode and the Command Line Tools installed. If I run

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

and

```
$xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

But then

```
$ gcc --version
-bash: gcc: command not found
```

It is entirely possible, the I deleted something I shouldn't have. Anyone have any clue on what I'm missing?

Note: I think the native XCode was installed, but I also successfully ran:

```
brew install gcc
brew link gcc
```

Still can't find gcc.

To add more details from questions:

```
$ which gcc
$
```

Gives no answer whatsoever and I DON'T have usr/bin/gcc or any similar folder (gcc4.9 or else). I tried reinstalling XCode without success and also tried reinstalling gcc through homebrew. It compiles and links just fine, but can't find the gcc.

Comment: Have you run the XCode gui and accepted the license terms? And have you tried running clang or cc instead of gcc? What is your path?

Comment: I did open and accepted in XCode gui. I had not tried clang. I get the following:

`$ clang`

`clang: error: no input files`

Comment: IIRC, gcc on modern OS X provided in XCode is just a link to clang, so you can call clang directly. If you run cc, it should call clang.But this doesn't answer your overall question. Maybe try reinstalling XCode and seeing if gcc comes back.

Comment: Do you have /usr/bin/gcc?

Comment: Have you tried `which gcc`?

Comment: Don't use the `gcc` that comes with Xcode. It's a horrible mess, that was used during the transition to clang, combining gcc-4.2.1 with the llvm backend. Install macports, make sure you know how to use the `select` subcommand, and a few others, and you can start using a full gcc-5.2 toolchain that's isolated (in /opt/local) from the system tools. Otherwise, set your `$CC`, `$CXX` in your shell to clang / clang++ and just use clang everywhere.

Comment: I added some details answering the questions:
which gcc gives no answer and I have no /usr/bin/gcc (or similar)
I've tried reinstalling everything with hombrew. It compiles and links just fine... but can't find the gcc...